# How to fill picture in SmartArt PowerPoint C#/VBA?

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint, office-interop

I have a shape in PowerPoint. I've checked the text in SmartArt but I don't know how to check the picture fill in SmartArt. Anyone can help me. Sorry if my English is not good.
I am looking forward to hearing from you.
Thanks

```
 bool SmartArtCheck()
{
    int t=0;
    GetActivePPFile();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= oPP.Slides[5].Shapes.Count; i++)
            if (oPP.Slides[5].Shapes[i].HasSmartArt.ToString() == "msoTrue")                
                {
                    string text = "";
                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Core.SmartArtNode node in oPP.Slides[5].Shapes[i].SmartArt.AllNodes)
                        text += node.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text;
                    if (text == "Step1Step2Step3" && oPP.Slides[5].Shapes[i].SmartArt.AllNodes.Count.ToString() == "3")
                        t++;
                }
    }
    catch { t = 1; }
    if (t == 2) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not all types (layout) of SmartArt in PowerPoint support filling pictures.

Luckily, the VerticalCurvedList in your question supports it!

```
Sub TestUpdateSmartArt()
Dim thisSlide As Slide, shapeItem As Shape
Set thisSlide = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1)
' test SmartArts
For j = 1 To thisSlide.Shapes.Count
    Set shapeItem = thisSlide.Shapes.Item(j)
    If shapeItem.HasSmartArt = True Then
        Debug.Print shapeItem.SmartArt.Layout.Id
'        If shapeItem.SmartArt.Layout.Id = "urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList" Then
        Dim node As SmartArtNode
            For Each node In shapeItem.SmartArt.AllNodes
                Debug.Print "shape count: " + Str(node.Shapes.Count)
                If node.Shapes.Count > 1 Then
                 ' the magic number 2 is different for different SmartArt layout
                 node.Shapes(2).Fill.UserPicture "C:\Users\user\test.png"
                End If
                Dim innerShape As Variant 'Shape
                For i = 1 To node.Shapes.Count
                    Set innerShape = node.Shapes.Item(i)
                    If innerShape.TextFrame2.HasText Then
                        Debug.Print Str(i) + " " + innerShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
                    End If
                Next
            Next
 '       End If
    
    End If
Next

End Sub
```